# Practice TFS free

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I just revised my first job as a developer. In my workplace we developing mainly in c# language.

In my work place there is a lot of use in source control and TFS which I'm not familiar with, my question: suppose I want to learn TFS in my spare time at house, is it possible? I don't have a pro account, I have visual studio 2017.

I don't mean to online courses, I need to do a "hands on" practice, i.e I need tfc on my own pc if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and run [TFS Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) or use [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) free for up to 5 users.

Or, ask if your company has a place where you can "play" on the live TFS instance, but in a test environment - I have setup separate "Team Project Collections" for people to experiment on.